# .NET RegEx: Replace unsanitary characters

Tags: .net, regex

Let's say I have a string that can contain any UTF-16 characters, but I want to replace all characters not in a whitelist with an underscore. Let's say the whitelist is [A-Za-z], [0-9], and [-:.].

How would I use the Regex class to replace all characters not in the whitelist?

Comment: Did you try `[^A-Za-z0-9-:.]`?

Comment: Might as well add an underscore to the list, and make it [^\w.:-]

Comment: "UTF-16" is an encoding, not a character set. Do you mean "Unicode" ?

Comment: *Unicode* is a standard, not a character set. Do you mean *Universal Character Set*?

Comment: “UTF-16” is both a byte encoding — actually two of them, UTF-16LE and UTF-16BE, plus a conceptual read-encoding where it could be either and is signalled by a BOM — *and* a 16-bit word encoding of code points into code units. It is a source of constant confusion that when you say “UTF-16” you could be talking about a sequence of bytes, or a sequence of 16-bit code units. Microsoft have not helped by calling both the code unit sequence and the UTF-16LE byte sequence just “Unicode”. Anyhow, in .NET you have UTF-16 code units and not Unicode characters as such. Enough pedantry for today!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it with this:

```
[^A-Za-z0-9:.-]
```

The caret is the negation operator.  So this will match every character that's not in the character class.

And then you simply replace the matches with an underscore like this:

```
Regex myRegex = new Regex(@"[^A-Za-z0-9:.-]", RegexOptions.Multiline);
return myRegex.Replace("your target string here", "_");
```

[Here it is in action](http://regexhero.net/tester/?id=0b1010e5-b958-4644-b51a-814e28113a93).

Comment: OK, done.  I guess I got nervous with dots and dashes in the character classes and I escaped them unnecessarily.  But it looks like it works exactly the same without the slashes.